# Twisted and adbapi - result has info about column name?

Tags: python, twisted

Is possible to find info about column name into result? It must be universal solution for any database.

My code

```
def runQuery(self, query, callback, *args, **kwargs):
  """A method for query with result.
  - query -- sql query
  - callback -- function with one argument
  """
  self.logmsg(_("Executing SQL query"))
  self.dbpool.start()
  d = self.dbpool.runQuery(query)
  self.dbpool.close()

  d.addCallback(callback)
```

To callback is given list of tuples. I need column name on first tuple or list of dictionaries.

Comment: This is my code, and I don't know how to do it. Maybe someone know what I should add to this code to get column name.

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2004-June/007968.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ConnectionPool` class then you can create a subclass of it and override its [`_runQuery`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py#L461) method:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

class MyConnectionPool(adbapi.ConnectionPool)

    def _runQuery(self, trans, *args, **kw):
        trans.execute(*args, **kw)
        data = trans.fetchall()
        if trans.description is not None:
            data = [tuple(c[0] for c in trans.description)] + list(data)
        return data
```

Comment: Subclassing instead of composing?  Sad. :(  Overriding private methods?  Super sad.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone That actually made me laugh. ;-) Anyways considering the `.fetchall()` part is executed under that private method I wasn't so sure what else could be done here. So, suggested this. But I guess Overriding or composing this class a passing a different function instead of `_runQuery` from `runQuery` should do the job. What do you think?